# Active Admin - Display only even number ids?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Can I add a button or click filter to a Products page on ActiveAdmin that only shows the even numbered id's?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. Have a look at how you can write your own collection action http://activeadmin.info/docs/8-custom-actions.html

Comment: You can use scope in Product model: `scope :even_ids, -> { where('id%2 = 0') }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :even_ids, -> { where('id%2 = 0') }
end

ActiveAdmin.register MyModel do
  scope :all, default: true
  scope :even_ids
end
```